# SeekBar: ProgressDrawable does only show after first progress Change

Tags: android, customization, seekbar

I want to implement a easy hsv color picker that fit well into my app. As known form color Pickers I would like to change the background of the seekBars according to the value of the other seekBars.

But when I start the activity I am seeing this:

[image]

After the first touch of one of the seekBars (no matter which) I get this result and after the first touch the layout stays like this and does not change with further touches (which is also what I would have expected according to my layout, the 2 seekBars on top are 20dip and the 1 below is as high as the thumb):

[image]

Like seen in the second picture I would like to have the seekBar from beginning.

Here my layout:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SbColorPickerHue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:max="360"
    android:thumb="@drawable/colorpickerthumb" />
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SbColorPickerSaturation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:max="255" 
    android:thumb="@drawable/colorpickerthumb"/>
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SbColorPickerValue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="255" 
    android:thumb="@drawable/colorpickerthumb"/>
```

With a OnSeekBarChangeListener in onProgressChanged() and of course in onCreate (to initalize the seekBars) I am calling the following function (To safe you a lot of code only the Hue Gradient is shown):

```
    private void setGradients() {
        mHueGradient = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,mColors);
        mHueGradient.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
        mHueGradient.setCornerRadius(mRadius);
        mHueGradient.setStroke(mStrokeWidth, mStrokeColor);
        mSbHue.setBackgroundDrawable(mHueGradient);
    }
```

I tried many different things already:

- set the Gradients twice in onCreate
- set the Gradients again in onRescume
- as can be seen in the layout xml I set some of the SeekBar to a fixed height (20dp) and others to wrap_content. The behaviour changed a little (as can be seen in the pictures). But still not satisfying.
- Invalidate either the seekBar or the Drawable
- Force Layout
- Measure the drawable

Result is always the same.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing somthing?

**Edit 1:**

The SeekBar and the ChangeListener are defined as follows:

```
    mSbHue = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SbColorPickerHue);
    setGradients();
    mSbHue.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            setGradients();
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you post the code where you declare the seekbars, their listeners, and the listener code?

Comment: Tried out some further things: update the drawable 1 sec after oncreate by a thread: no change. Add the seekbar programatically to the view: no change. Im am totally out of ideas now...

Comment: By the way: testes this behaviour on 4 devices: 2 htc, motorola, samsung galaxy nexus: everwhere same result...

Comment: try adding some Log messages in setGradients to ensure it is getting called when you interact with the seekbar

Comment: I checked that already before. setGradients() definitly called in OnCreate() and on every ProgressChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move setGradients() after the listener it works.

```
mSbHue = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SbColorPickerHue);
mSbHue.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        setGradients();
    }
});
setGradients();
```

Comment: No. At first I had it in front of. Then I tried like you said setGradients() after the Listeners. Then I tried once in front of and once after. Nothing changed at all.

Comment: Well...I did have the same issue than you at the beginning. Then I moved setGradients. Maybe i could publish my test project so you can see it really works?

Comment: sure. Its not like I want to reject your answer :) If it is of any help I can upload the color picker class complete.

Comment: Ah, we are coming closer: You set the BackgroundDrawable. If I use your code and set the progressDrawable then the behaviour is same. Which brought me now to a Workaround: Like in your code I set the BackgroundDrawable and set the Progressdrawable to a colorDrawable (with 0x00000000) as color. Thanks a lot!